# Angular 2 Jasmine error: Can't resolve all parameters for NgRedux

Tags: angular, jasmine, redux

I am using `ngRedux` with angular 2.

I am trying to test a simple component which uses `ngRedux`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgRedux, select } from 'ng2-redux';
import { CustomerProfileModel, rootReducer } from '../common/customerProfileReducer';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile-details',
  templateUrl: './profile-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile-details.component.css']
})
export class ProfileDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  customerUIData: object;

  constructor(
    private ngRedux: NgRedux<Map<string, any>>) {
    this.ngRedux.subscribe(() => {
      this.getDataFromStore()
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() { this.getDataFromStore()}

  getDataFromStore() {
    var store = this.ngRedux.getState();
    this.customerUIData = store;
  }

}
```

My unit test looks like this:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { NgRedux, select, NgReduxModule } from 'ng2-redux';
import { ProfileDetailsComponent } from './profile-details.component';
import { CustomerProfileModel, rootReducer } from '../common/customerProfileReducer';

describe('ProfileDetailsComponent', () => {
  let component: ProfileDetailsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProfileDetailsComponent>;
  let ngRedux: NgRedux<CustomerProfileModel>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ProfileDetailsComponent],
      providers: [NgRedux],
      imports:[NgReduxModule]
    })
      .compileComponents();

  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProfileDetailsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

`Redux` store is as below:

```
export interface CustomerProfileModel {
    customerData: {
        ....
    };
}

export const CUSTPROFILE_INITIAL_STATE: CustomerProfileModel = {
    customerData: {
        ....
    }
};

export function rootReducer(state: CustomerProfileModel, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'GET_CUSTOMER_PROFILE_SUCCESS':
          return { customerData: action.customerData };
    }
    return state;
}
```

I am getting error as below

```
Failed: Can't resolve all parameters for NgRedux: (?).
```

Can anyone help me figure out what parameters i need to put?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove "providers: [NgRedux]," as it is not needed to add NgRedux to your providers if you are already using NgReduxModule.

Comment: done !! Now i am getting another error: _this._store is null

Comment: I am not familiar with Redux but I think you will need to mock the "this.ngRedux.getState()" to return a mockstore.